# PHP translate and template engine

Tags: php, oop, templates, translate

I'm working on my new CMS and i tried to create template engine. And i added translate system on that, but don't works good.
Here is my class for template:

```
    <?php

class Template {
    private $vars = array();

    public function assign($key, $value){
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function render($template_name){
        $path = 'templates/default/'.$template_name.'.html';

        if(file_exists($path)){
            $contents = file_get_contents($path);

            foreach($this->vars as $key => $value){
                $contents = preg_replace('/\['.$key.'\]/', $value, $contents);
            }

            $site_theme = 'default';
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- if (.*) \-\-\>/', '<?php if($1) : ?>', $contents);
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- else \-\-\>/', '<?php else : ?>', $contents);
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- endif \-\-\>/', '<?php endif; ?>', $contents);
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- include:(.*) \-\-\>/', '<?php include "templates/$site_theme/$1"; ?>', $contents);
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- is_logged \-\-\>/', '<?php logged() ? include "templates/'.$site_theme.'/logged.html" : logged(); ?>', $contents);
            $contents = preg_replace('/\<\!\-\- not_logged \-\-\>/', '<?php logged() ? : include "templates/'.$site_theme.'/unlogged.html"; ?>', $contents);

            eval(' ?> '.$contents. ' <?php '); 
        } else {
            // What if i told you template don't exist?
            exit('<h1>Template path don't exist. </h1>');
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Index:

```
<?php

        $template = new Template;

    $template->assign('lang_title', $lang['cat_categories']);

    $template->render('index');

?>
```

Translate file:

```
<?php

$lang['db_connect_failed']      = 'Unable connect to database';


$lang['cat_categories']     = 'Categories';

?>
```

And, this is my problem:
Everything works when i add [variable] in my templates/default/index.html file, and it show what need to be shown. But, when i add including files in template, eg:
templates/default/inc/header.html and in that file add my variable it don't work. I include that file in my index.html which is in parent folder using PHP or my modified HTML comment it doesn't work. I want add [lang_translate] in my included file or $lang['cat_categories'] (that don't work even in index.html) in header or index to show translation.

All file paths are okay and works. What i can do now?

Answer (score 0):

Then doing this should work maybe:

```
// function names migt differ. Check output buffering on php.net
Ob_start();
include index.html;
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

Now the contents would have the header file too. Btw, I would suggest you use a template engine. Using eval on an unknown template file created by someone might be risky.